# Troubles with Docker + PHP7 + GD resulting in "Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()"

Tags: php, docker, gd, php-gd

I'm having troubles when trying to create an image using `imagecreatefromjpeg` using this `Dockerfile` to generate the container:

```
FROM  php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -qq git \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        apt-transport-https \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        zip unzip \
        nodejs \
        npm \
        wget \
        vim

RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt zip pdo pdo_mysql gd bcmath

COPY ./containers/yii.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN for mod in rewrite headers; do a2enmod $mod; done && service apache2 restart

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
```

GD was correctly installed (libjpeg too - both appearing in `php -i` and `phpinfo()`) but `imagecreatefromjpeg` does not works and I don't know why.

---

I also ran `apt install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev` trying to ~force~ reinstallation (or reconfiguration) but seems doesn't succeded (yes, I also restart the container).

```
root@e8db647c96c4:/var/www/html# php -i | grep -i GD
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini,
gd
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
root@e8db647c96c4:/var/www/html#
```

---

```
root@e8db647c96c4:/var/www/html# docker-php-ext-enable gd

warning: gd (gd.so) is already loaded!

root@e8db647c96c4:/var/www/html#
```

---

I've tried `apt install libgd2-xpm-dev*` and apparently it doesn't solves the problem.

---

#### Solved

I was missing to put

```
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

into my Dockerfile.

---

Full revised Dockerfile:

```
FROM  php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -qq git \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        apt-transport-https \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        zip unzip \
        nodejs \
        npm \
        wget \
        vim

RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt zip pdo pdo_mysql gd bcmath

COPY ./containers/yii.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN for mod in rewrite headers; do a2enmod $mod; done && service apache2 restart

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
```

Comment: The `docker-php-ext-configure gd` command was what I needed to sold a similar error. Thanks!

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.

Comment: The new version of PHP 7.4 does not have the options `--with-freetype-dir` and `--with-jpeg-dir` anymore. Instead, I used the options `--with-freetype` and `--with-jpeg` and my testsuite turned green again.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### PHP 7.4 (Alpine)

If anybody is struggling to enable JPEG support in GD with **PHP 7.4**, here's what I had to do in order to be able to use `imagecreatefromjpeg()` function.
My example is based on Alpine 3.10, if you're using other distribution adjust it to your needs.

First install dependencies, in my case beside JPEG I need support for PNG files.

```
apk add jpeg-dev libpng-dev
```

After that we can run `docker-php-ext-configure` command to configure our gd with JPEG support. Notice that flag `--with-jpeg-dir` was changed to `--with-jpeg` and we don't need to provide flag to enable PNG. More you can read in [PHP 7.4 Changelog](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.other-changes.php) in GD section.

```
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg
```

Directly after that let's run `docker-php-ext-install` to install GD itself.

```
docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

FULL EXAMPLE

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.10

RUN apk add jpeg-dev libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: The package for me was `libjpeg-dev` rather than `jpeg-dev`

Comment: in PHP 7.3 I used libjpeg-dev & --with-jpeg-dir and it worked!

Answer (score 12):

For PHP 5.6

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev \ 
libgd-dev libpng12-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \ 
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \ 
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

If still not working, can re-install the container.

```
docker rm <container id> 
docker-compose build --pull
docker-compose up
```

Comment: In your above example of the contents of the Dockerfile, Is the path `/usr/include/` inside the container or on the host machine? I believe that a Dockerfile can only refer to paths within it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448821/how-to-write-data-to-host-file-system-from-docker-container (thanks)

Comment: Correct, the path is inside the container.

Comment: If you receive the error `Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate` ( which was dropped some time ago ) you can change `libpng12-dev` to `libpng-dev` to make it work

Answer (score 4):

Updated Version PHP 7.4 + Apache:

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y sendmail libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libgd-dev libpng-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql 

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \ 
--with-freetype=/usr/include/ \ 
--with-jpeg=/usr/include/

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these Commands

```
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg 
docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Working full Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /src/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /src

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql exif pcntl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction

COPY . /src

RUN chmod 777 -R /src/storage

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```