# Is there a way to view WSL2 docker container's files via Windows File Explorer?

Tags: docker, containers, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I can `bash` into one of the containers, but sometimes it's much easier to view it in GUI app such as Windows File Explorer or Total Commander.

Is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want is to view folder inside your container while in development,
you can use the `BIND MOUNTS`: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/, which is kind of `volume`

This allows you to set "full" connection between your container specific folder to an input folder within your local machine.

You can apply it via ternimal with: `docker run ......... -v <path_within_your_local_machine>:<path_within_container_file_system>`.

Comment: It's creating the folder, but it's empty

Comment: @Tar Please provide at least partial code of what you have been trying.

Comment: Issuing this command: `docker run --rm -it -v c:\aaa\cont:/srv/my my-image` results in a new directory being created at `c:\aaa\cont`, but this directory is empty. There must be something, as `/srv/my` isn't empty.

Comment: you can use the command `docker cp`. documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

@Tar

Comment: Yep, that's working, but it's not a direct access to the container.

Comment: What do you mean by direct access? Because this `docker cp` command does copy your direct files/folders off your container file system. Anyway, If you do want continuous connection, you need to use the `bind mount` option.

Comment: Generally, `bind mount` option does copy your non-existence files & folders locally from docker container file system into your local file system. The command you have executed should have done the work. Maybe provide some more details

Comment: You might want to have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448821/how-to-write-data-to-host-file-system-from-docker-container
It states your problem, and specifically I'd reckon on focusing in "Software Engineer" Answer

Comment: it makes sense indeed that files are being copied, but it's behind the scenes. I do want to try the method you suggested - `bind mount`. But I may be missing something, as it's not working: issuing `docker run --rm -it -v c:\aaa\cont:/srv/my my-image` merely creating an empty directory for me, I'm not seeing all the files that reside in that directory. Again, I believe that I'm missing something, but unsure what...

Comment: @Tar As I do not have access to your complete project files, the only option I got you is to follow the link I've provided in my previous comment. Or - you could create brand new question which focueses on your problem with `BIND MOUNT`